# How do I re-sign a debug signed apk such that the mp3 files are not compressed?

Tags: android, maven, jarsigner

I have some mp3 files in my res/raw/ folder when it first gets signed with android debug key the mp3 file bundled with the apk is not compressed.

I verify this by typing unzip -lv  and i get this

```
1670  Stored     1670   0%  06-23-14 18:48  3b4b6017  res/raw/swipe.mp3
```

then it gets re-signed as a part of the build job using jarsigner plugin I have
    **removeExistingSignatures** set to **true**
after that when i run unzip -lv the method of the mp3 is Defl:N instead of Stored (i.e it gets compressed)

I need it to be in Stored state even after re-signing becasue i get this error if the mp3 file is compressed

```
07-17 03:36:00.068 E/AndroidRuntime( 9487): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3

07-17 03:36:00.068 E/AndroidRuntime( 9487): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/swipe.mp3 from drawable resource ID #0x7f060000

07-17 03:36:00.068 E/AndroidRuntime( 9487):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:982)

07-17 03:36:00.068 E/AndroidRuntime( 9487):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:874)

07-17 03:36:00.068 E/AndroidRuntime( 9487):     at <my_package_here>
07-17 03:36:00.068 E/AndroidRuntime( 9487):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)

07-17 03:36:00.068 E/AndroidRuntime( 9487):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)

07-17 03:36:00.068 E/AndroidRuntime( 9487):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)

07-17 03:36:00.068 E/AndroidRuntime( 9487):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

07-17 03:36:00.068 E/AndroidRuntime( 9487): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
```

I am not able to get it directly signed with my key. in spite of setting 
`<sign><debug>false</debug></sign>` in my android-maven-plugin it gets signed with the android debug key.

How do i sign directly with my key ? Or how do i re-sign such that the mp3 file is not compressed?

Answer (score 1):

Inside of putting it inside Raw, you can put it in the assets folder. To access files from the asset folder you can [getAssets()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getAssets()).

For example to get a File object you can do :

```
File f = new File(getAssets().open("music/something.mp3"));
```

Comment: You're missing a ')' at the end. (Can't edit it since it's less than 6 characters)